# Visiting my sub site automatically signs the user out from the parent site

Tags: asp.net-membership

I have a parent site where i setup all the settings in the web.config

The sub site is a separate application, but i intetialy don't have a web.config file there, so that it should inherit all settings from its parent site

But nevertheless i can sign in both sites, but signing into the parent site will automatically sign the user out from the sub site. how is that?

Answer (score 1):

You are not writing what authentication you are using.

COOKIES: Is one cookie overwriting the other?
WEB.CONFIG: is the subweb a different application? (it should, so they don't interfere)
HTACCESS: